# Ajax / PHP: How to pass and receive array between Ajax and PHP (code partially working)

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am new to Ajax and PHP and hope someone can help me with this.

I need to generate an array with unique IDs in jQuery, pass it to a PHP page and return the corresponding values from the PHP page.

So far I have the following code which works on the jQuery side so the first `console.log` logs the input array correctly, e.g. `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`.

However, I am not getting any results from the PHP page and the second `console.log` logs nothing for the output array so I guess I am missing one or more things there. 
**The result should be an associative array where each item is listed with its tID and the corresponding value from the MySQL query**, like `"tID" => "1", "value" => "value1"` ... .

Can someone help me with this ?

**JS side:**

```
function getValues(languageFrm){
    var values = [],
        tID;

    $('.valuesDynamic').find('.values').each(function(){
        tID = $(this).attr('name').replace('tID', '');
        if($.inArray(tID, values) === -1){
            values.push(tID);
        }
    });
    values.sort();
    console.log(values);

    $.ajax({        
        type: "post",   
        url: "ajax.php",
        cache: "false",
        data: {
            node: 'fetchValues',
            values: values,
            languageFrm: languageFrm
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP side:**

```
case "fetchValues":
    $values = $_POST["values"];
    $languageFrm = $_POST["languageFrm"];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tID, " . $languageFrm . " FROM main WHERE tID IN(?) ORDER BY tID");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", implode(",", $values));
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($arrValues = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $result[] = array("tID" => $arrValues["tID"], "value" => $arrValues[$languageFrm]);
    }

    echo $result;
    break;
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could JSON encode you array and then JSON decode on PHP side.

For your JS side, you would replace your data section with:

```
 data: {
            node: 'fetchValues',
            values: JSON.stringify(values),
            languageFrm: languageFrm
        },
```

for PHP. instead of `$values = $_POST["values"]`, you would do:

```
$values = json_decode($_POST["values"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! Will give it a try. I read about this in some other posts and it seemed to me that jQuery would do this automatically so that stringify wouldn't be needed here.

Comment: Not sure actually if this is the case, but you can easily check by var_dumping that variable.

var_dump($_POST["values"]);

This will show you precisely what is inside and if in fact it is already json encoded, you can simply leave it as is and do only json_decode on PHP side.

Comment: I tried your approach but it doesn't change anything for me so the result is still empty in this case.

Comment: What does var_dump return?

Comment: Then the problem is on JS side... Nothing gets passed to PHP.

Comment: Are $_POST['languageFrm'] and $_POST['node'] there when you dump them?

Comment: You can also preview what exactly is being send on that request e.g. using Chrome's Developer Tools in Net tab. It will show you what data is being posted by your scripts within the request. If you past the exact post content, we might be able to help you more :)

Comment: Thanks again. I went through the code again after your comments and found a typo. After fixing this it works perfect with your suggestions ! :) - Sorry, didn't see that straight away.

Comment: @TaneMahuta What about my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `PHP SIDE` should be

```
case "fetchValues":
$values = implode(",", $_POST["values"]);
$languageFrm = $_POST["languageFrm"];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tID, " . $languageFrm . " FROM main WHERE tID IN($values) ORDER BY tID");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($arrValues = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $result[] = array("tID" => $arrValues["tID"], "value" => $arrValues[$languageFrm]);
}

echo $result;
break;
```

In other words you must put `$values` directly in your query

Comment: Thanks for this - would that still prevent SQL injection ?

Comment: I tried this and it returns a fatal error "Call to a member function execute() on a non-object...".

Answer (score 0):

**JS Side**

```
data: {
            node: 'fetchValues',
            values: $.extend({},values),
            languageFrm: languageFrm
        },
```

**PHP Side**

`$result` is an array. so replace `echo $result;` with `print_r($result);`